# SQL2005: Linking a table to multiple tables and retaining Ref Integrity?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, referential-integrity

Here is a simplification of my database:

```
Table: Property
Fields: ID, Address

Table: Quote
Fields: ID, PropertyID, BespokeQuoteFields...

Table: Job
Fields: ID, PropertyID, BespokeJobFields...
```

Then we have other tables that relate to the **Quote** and **Job** tables individually.

I now need to add a **Message** table where users can record telephone messages left by customers regarding Jobs and Quotes.

I could create two identical tables (**QuoteMessage** and **JobMessage**), but this violates the DRY principal and seems messy.

I could create one **Message** table:

```
Table: Message
Fields: ID, RelationID, RelationType, OtherFields...
```

But this stops me from using constraints to enforce my referential integrity.  I can also forsee it creating problems with the devlopment side using Linq to SQL later on.

Is there an elegant solution to this problem, or am I ultimately going to have to hack something together?

Burns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create one Message table, containing a unique MessageId and the various properties you need to store for a message.

```
Table: Message
Fields: Id, TimeReceived, MessageDetails, WhateverElse...
```

Create two link tables - QuoteMessage and JobMessage. These will just contain two fields each, foreign keys to the Quote/Job and the Message.

```
Table: QuoteMessage
Fields: QuoteId, MessageId

Table: JobMessage
Fields: JobId, MessageId
```

In this way you have defined the data properties of a Message in one place only (making it easy to extend, and to query across all messages), but you also have the referential integrity linking Quotes and Jobs to any number of messages. Indeed, both a Quote and Job could be linked to the *same* message (I'm not sure if that is appropriate to your business model, but at least the data model gives you the option).

Answer (score 1):

About the only other way I can think of is to have a base Message table, with both an Id and a TypeId. Your subtables (QuoteMessage and JobMessage) then reference the base table on both MessageId and TypeId - but also have CHECK CONSTRAINTS on them to enforce only the appropiate MessageTypeId.

```
Table: Message
Fields: Id, MessageTypeId, Text, ...
Primary Key: Id, MessageTypeId
Unique: Id

Table: MessageType
Fields: Id, Name
Values: 1, "Quote" : 2, "Job"

Table: QuoteMessage
Fields: Id, MessageId, MessageTypeId, QuoteId
Constraints: MessageTypeId = 1
References: (MessageId, MessageTypeId) = (Message.Id, Message.MessageTypeId)
            QuoteId = Quote.QuoteId

Table: JobMessage
Fields: Id, MessageId, MessageTypeId, JobId
Constraints: MessageTypeId = 2
References: (MessageId, MessageTypeId) = (Message.Id, Message.MessageTypeId)
            JobId = Job.QuoteId
```

What does this buy you, as compared to just a JobMesssage and QuoteMessage table? It elevates a Message to a first class citizen, so that you can read all Messages from a single table. In exchange, your query path from a Message to it's relevant Quote or Job is 1 more join away. It kind of depends on your app flow whether that's a good tradeoff or not.

As for 2 identical tables violating DRY - I wouldn't get hung up on that. In DB design, it's less about DRY, and more about normalization. If the 2 things you're modeling have the same attributes (columns), but are actually different things (tables) - then it's reasonable to have multiple tables with similar schemas. Much better than the reverse of munging different things together.

Answer (score 1):

@burns

Ian's answer (+1) is correct *[see note]*.  Using a many to many table `QUOTEMESSAGE` to join `QUOTE` to `MESSAGE` is the most correct model, but will leave orphaned `MESSAGE` records.

This is one of those *rare* cases where a trigger can be used.  However, caution needs to be applied to ensure that the a single `MESSAGE` record cannot be associated with both a `QUOTE` and a `JOB`.

```
create trigger quotemessage_trg
on quotemessage
for delete
as
begin

delete 
from [message] 
where [message].[msg_id] in 
    (select [msg_id] from Deleted);

end
```

*Note to Ian, I think there is a typo in the table definition for `JobMessage`, where the columns should be `JobId, MessageId` (?).  I would edit your quote but it might take me a few years to gain that level of reputation!*

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have both QuoteId and JobId fields in the message table? Or does a message have to be regarding either a quote or a job and not both?